# How would you execute npm install with a specific version from the nexus repo

Tags: npm, installation, nexus

How to execute npm install with a specific version from the nexus repo?

My artifacts are stored in Nexus. what I need to do is execute `npm install <nexus version>`. However when I do this it still uses my latest package.json that I committed. I want to use all artifacts including package.json from the version in my nexus repo.

Comment: The simple edit by James Z changes the question IMO.  I answered the original quesiton as I don't believe the ask is to install Nexus thru npm, it's to install versions of packages thru Nexus (NXRM).

Answer (score 0):

Using npm via NXRM behaves the same as using npm without NXRM as far as installs go.  You can use `npm install package@version`.

So for example, `npm install pluto@0.4.0`.

See [npm install doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) for more details.